# JPQL and ON clause basic subquery

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

In MySQL, This works and I want to achieve equivalent with hibernate:

```
Select * from A a left join B b on a.id=b.id AND b.lenght=20
```

There is `OneToMany()`: `Class A` contains `List <B> b`

With hibernate I got stuck on that:

```
//the ON clause comes from the mapping's join columns and is handled automatically 
@Query(Select a from A a left join a.b c)
```

but I dont know how to add this part `AND b.lenght=20`

Hot to translate it to JPQL with JPA?

Comment: FWIW JPA uses JPQL, not "HQL"

Comment: JPQL and "HQL" they pretty much are the same. Very small differences at all.

Comment: One is portable, and the other isn't; the *crucial* difference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add your condition in the join clause using the WITH keyword

```
Select a from A a left join a.b with b.lenght = 20
```

... assuming `lenght` is a field in B, not the length function.

[https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/queryhql.html]

Comment: yup, lenght is a field in B

Comment: WITH is not valid JPQL. Suggest you make that clear in your answer, that the user is throwing away vendor independence, when there is a JPA standard "ON" clause available ...

Comment: You mean like "LEFT JOIN a.b b ON b.length = 20" ? that you would find in the JPA 2.1 spec